# maven dependency report: avoid delay and error messages for (glassfish) repository

Tags: maven, repository, maven-site-plugin

When I run the `site` build of [Apache Commons VFS2](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/) the dependency-report plugin tries to fill a matrix, which artifact can be obtained by which repository.

In my case it also tries to inspect the maven.glassfish.org repository, which is AFAIK abandoned. But since it is still on some of the used dependency POMs, it is still showing up in my project (and I guess I cant influence that easily).

```
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[ERROR] Unable to determine if resource asm:asm:jar:3.1:provided exists in http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/glassfish
...
```

This not only produces a lot of errors, it also takes time. Besides I would want to limit the columns in the report to the repositories which are relevant for this project.

I wonder, is there a way to make the plugin (and all of Maven) skip specific repositories? How would you blacklist them in my [project POM](https://github.com/apache/commons-vfs/blob/trunk/pom.xml)?

The `dependency:list-repositories` goal does not show this repo, but when I search through all cached POM files I see `<id>glassfish-repository</id>` in `com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.8`.

Answer (score 1):

**Choose one of these:**

1. The correct answer is for them to remove the repository from the pom definition.
   See [Why Putting Repositories in your POMs is a Bad Idea](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea). There should be no reason why other open source projects are not hosted there.
   To convince the other repositories to publish their projects to Central, point them at the docs http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html, or you can do the upload for them. If it's only a few artifacts that might be the easiest.

Remember, every extra repo defined in the pom impacts **your** build's performance, 
as Maven must check **each** repo for artifacts. It's not a big
problem if you only have to add one repo... But the problem grows and next
thing you know your maven build is checking 50 repos for every artifact and
build time is a dog. See this [email thread](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Using-github-as-a-maven-repo-td5787022.html#a5787029) for more details about the impact.

2. The next best answer, if that project is abandoned, is you could patch the pom to remove the repository definition and re-upload the patched pom and the unchanged jar to Maven Central. See [Guide to uploading artifacts to the Central Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html)

---

**Avoid these options**

Every other option here is a hack and choosing any of these option will mean everyone else will need to make the same changes to fix the problem.

3. Blacklist the repository by disabling it in your [*settings.xml* file](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-settings/settings.html). Unfortunately there is no unique identifier for a repository. The *repository > id* field can be anything the person creating the pom defines, and so the same repository url can be referenced with different ids. To find the id run with the *-X* option and the debug output should list the repositories id. Use something like this to disable it:

```html
<repository>
  <releases>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </releases>
  <id>the repo id from X here</id>
  <name>the repo's name</name>
  <url>the repo's url</url>
</repository>
```

4. Force the repository to use a mirror instead. Much like 3 but to redirect the broken repository to another one.

```html
<mirror>
  <id>Another Mirror</id>
  <url>url to mirror</url>
  <mirrorOf>id of broken repo</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

5. Force the repository to use a local [Maven Repository Manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) instead (even on your laptop). This was, no matters who abuses repositories in a pom, 
   Maven will only contact your local MRM and avoid multiple, slow, network connections for each defined repo.

```html
<mirror>
  <id>Local MRM</id>
  <url>url to MRM</url>
  <!-- Mirror EVERYTHING to your MRM -->
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Comment: Yes I typically use my own mirror, but for the purpose of this dependency report it is not good to have one, as it falsely shows the artifacts available on them. (And it does not help me to get the repo removed from the report)

Comment: Have you tried disabling that repository?
http://maven.apache.org/settings.html -> <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>

Comment: disabling in settings.xml helps against loading, thanks (see chnaged question on how to find the id). But I figured out since only one unneeded transitive dependency is draged in with the broken repo, I just excluded that one. This is better as it does not need a local modification and it removes the column from the depenedency locations report.